# Use of predefined Tailwind codes in Next JS

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, vite

I'm converting a Vite JS project to Next JS and need to import my Tailwind styles from a file. My project is reading the file but it's not applying the styles as I expected.

Is is it possible to use this or a similar method for Next JS.

```js
// styles.js file in styles folder of Next JS Project
export const styles = { padding: "sm:px-8 py-3" };

// Usage in any component in Next JS Project
import { styles } from "../styles/styles.js";

const About = () => (
 <div className={`${styles.padding} text-white`}>
  ...
 </div>
)
```

Comment: You'll need to share the contents of your `tailwind.config.js` file to get actual help but my guess is that you don't have the proper file types or paths in the `content` section https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Comment: Hi @JHeth. Since I couldn't post all the codes here, I added them as a comment below.

Comment: From this `content: ["./components/**/*.{js,jsx}", "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx}"],` it looks like you certainly do not have your `styles` folder listed, so Tailwind is not looking there. If the `components` and `pages` folders are in the same directory as the `styles` folder then you can probably just copy one of those declarations and change the path to `styles`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @JHeth . "content: ["./components/**/*.{js,jsx}", "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx}", "./styles/styles.js"]", My problem was solved when I edited the code like this. Thanks again and again. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of the Tailwind file. I tried to try several ways with ChatGPT. But unfortunately I was not successful.

```js
// import { styles } from '@/styles/styles.js';

// const {styles} = require('./styles/styles');


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./components/**/*.{js,jsx}", "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#050816",
        secondary: "#aaa6c3",
        tertiary: "#151030",
        "black-100": "#100d25",
        "black-200": "#090325",
        "white-100": "#f3f3f3",
      },
      boxShadow: {
        card: "0px 35px 120px -15px #211e35",
      },
      screens: {
        xs: "450px",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "hero-pattern": "url('/assets/herobg.png')",
      },
      // ...styles,
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).